# Updates text but not style manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not even sure how this is possible or I'm just completely stupid... it works sometimes but does not work most of the time... I've cleared cache and all that... Using Chrome browser... tried debugging in chrome but still nothing... No console errors on my end... The green dot should be red... Yet it is not... However text appears perfectly fine...

```js
function init()
{
 updateIS2data();
    setInterval(updateIS2data, 1000);
}

function updateIS2data()
{
 var BP = 100;//getBatteryPercent();
 var BS = 2//getBatteryState();
 var LPM = "false";//isLowPower();
 var txtLPM = "";
 
 document.getElementById("battLevel").innerHTML = txtLPM + " " + BP + "%";
 var BatteryImage = document.getElementById('BatteryImageLevel');
 if(BP > 95){ w = 20; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(50, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 95 && BP > 90) { w = 19; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(75, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 90 && BP > 85) {  w = 18; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(100, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 85 && BP > 80) {  w = 17; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(125, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 80 && BP > 75) {  w = 16;  BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(150, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 75 && BP > 70) {  w = 15; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(175, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 70 && BP > 65) {  w = 14; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(200, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 65 && BP > 60) {  w = 13; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(225, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 60 && BP > 55) {  w = 12; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 55 && BP > 50) {  w = 11; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 195, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 50 && BP > 45) {  w = 10; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 165, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 45 && BP > 40) {  w = 9; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 155, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 40 && BP > 35) {  w = 8; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 145, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 35 && BP > 30) {  w = 7; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 135, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 30 && BP > 25) {  w = 6; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 125, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 25 && BP > 20) {  w = 5; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 115, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 20 && BP > 15) {  w = 4; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 105, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 15 && BP > 10) {  w = 3; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 95, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 10 && BP > 5) {  w = 2; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 85, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 5 && BP > 0) {  w = 1; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(205, 50, 50)"; }
 BatteryImage.style.width = w;
 
 if(BS == 1) document.getElementById('isCharging').style.display = "none";
 else if(BS == 2) document.getElementById('isCharging').style.display = "block";
 
 var dLPM = document.getElementById("isLowPowerMode");
 if(LPM == "false")
 {
  dLPM.innerHTML = "Testing";
  dLPM.style.backgroundColor = "red;";
 } else {
  dLPM.style.position = "asfdasfdasfd";
 }


 //RAM Stats//
 //document.getElementById("freeRam").innerHTML = getRam() + "MB";
 document.getElementById("freeRam").innerHTML = "1000MB";

 //devicename//
 //document.getElementById("dName").innerHTML = deviceName();
 document.getElementById("dName").innerHTML = "ShadowEvil's iPhone";
}
```

```css
html
{
 position:absolute;
 margin:0px 0px;
 padding: 0;
}

@font-face
{
 font-family: def;
 src: url(../Fonts/Nokio-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
 font-family: def1;
 src: url(../Fonts/Nokio-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
 font-family: def2;
 src: url(../Fonts/Nokio-Medium.ttf);
}

body
{
 background: url('../Images/bg.png') no-repeat;
 background-size: 320px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#battLevel
{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:27px;
 left: -30px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 z-index:15;
 text-align:right;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
} 

#BatteryImage
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 22px;
 height: 7px;
 top:29px;
 left: 292px;
 z-index:10;
 border: 1px solid white;
 Border-radius: 15px;
}

#isCharging
{
 margin-top: -6px;
 margin: -6px auto 0 auto;
 width: 20px;
 height: 7px;
 background: url('../Images/charging.png') no-repeat;
}

#isLowPowerMode
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 254px;
 top: 29px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 z-index: 15;
 background-color: limegreen;
 Border-radius: 10px;
}

#BatteryImage #BatteryImageLevel
{
 margin-top: 1px;
 margin-left: 1px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 5px;
 z-index:15;
 background-color: limegreen;
 Border-radius: 15px;
}

#freeRam{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:27px;
 left:0px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index:15;
}

#dName
{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:21px;
 left:0px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 z-index:15;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#DateWrap
{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:30px;
 left:0px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 z-index:16;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#line{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:42px;
  width:320px;
  Border-radius:0;
  background-color: #383838;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:0.85;
}
#circle3{
  position: absolute;
  top:21px;
  left:250px;
  height:45px;
  width:45px;
  Border-radius:100px;
  background-color:383838;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:1.0;
}
#circle4{
  position: absolute;
  top:26px;
  left:256px;
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
  Border-radius:100px;
  background-color:fffffd;
  border: 1px solid none;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>P.iW.14</title>
<!--Scripts JunesiPhone, IS2 Matchstic, mod J3T,-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, height=568, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <script src="Config.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/Library/lang.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<script src="js/IS2.js"></script>
<script src="js/Library/clock.js"></script>
<script type="text/cycript">
      var getBatteryPercent = function() { return [IS2System batteryPercent]; };
   var getBatteryState = function() { return [IS2System batteryStateAsInteger]; };
   var getRam = function() { return [IS2System ramFree]; };
   var getSignal = function() { return [IS2Telephony phoneSignalBars]; }; 
   var airplaneMode = function() { return [IS2Telephony airplaneModeEnabled]; }
   var WifiOn = function() { return [IS2Telephony dataConnectionAvailableViaWiFi]; }; 
   var WifiSignal = function() { return [IS2Telephony wifiSignalBars]; }; 
   var deviceName = function() { return [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]; };
   var isLowPower = function() { return [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isLowPowerModeEnabled]; };
</script>

<body onload="init()">
<!--Library that handles clock info NO-EDIT-->
       <div id="DateWrap">
  <a id="month"></a> <a id="date"></a> <a id="year"></a>
       </div>
    <script src="js/clockMain.js"></script>
<!--END Clock Widget-->

<div id="line"></div>
<div id="isLowPowerMode"></div>
<div id="battLevel"></div>
<div id="BatteryImage"><div id="BatteryImageLevel"></div><div id="isCharging"></div></div>
<div id="freeRam"></div>
<div id="dName"></div>

<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;

if(width == 375)
{
 viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
 viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.18, maximum-scale=1.18, user-scalable=0');
} else if(width == 414 ) {
 viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
 viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.3, maximum-scale=1.3, user-scalable=0');
}

</script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Semi-colons are not necessary when adding inline-styles. They will cause an error.
dLPM.style.backgroundColor = "red";

```js
function init()
{
 updateIS2data();
    setInterval(updateIS2data, 1000);
}

function updateIS2data()
{
 var BP = 10;//getBatteryPercent();
 var BS = 2//getBatteryState();
 var LPM = "false";//isLowPower();
 var txtLPM = "";
 
 document.getElementById("battLevel").innerHTML = txtLPM + " " + BP + "%";
 var BatteryImage = document.getElementById('BatteryImageLevel');
 if(BP > 95){ w = 20; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(50, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 95 && BP > 90) { w = 19; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(75, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 90 && BP > 85) {  w = 18; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(100, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 85 && BP > 80) {  w = 17; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(125, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 80 && BP > 75) {  w = 16;  BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(150, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 75 && BP > 70) {  w = 15; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(175, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 70 && BP > 65) {  w = 14; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(200, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 65 && BP > 60) {  w = 13; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(225, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 60 && BP > 55) {  w = 12; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 205, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 55 && BP > 50) {  w = 11; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 195, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 50 && BP > 45) {  w = 10; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 165, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 45 && BP > 40) {  w = 9; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 155, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 40 && BP > 35) {  w = 8; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 145, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 35 && BP > 30) {  w = 7; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 135, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 30 && BP > 25) {  w = 6; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 125, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 25 && BP > 20) {  w = 5; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 115, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 20 && BP > 15) {  w = 4; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 105, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 15 && BP > 10) {  w = 3; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 95, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 10 && BP > 5) {  w = 2; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(250, 85, 50)"; }
 else if(BP <= 5 && BP > 0) {  w = 1; BatteryImage.style.backgroundColor = "RGB(205, 50, 50)"; }
 BatteryImage.style.width = w;
 
 if(BS == 1) document.getElementById('isCharging').style.display = "none";
 else if(BS == 2) document.getElementById('isCharging').style.display = "block";
 
 var dLPM = document.getElementById("isLowPowerMode");
 if(LPM == "false")
 {
  dLPM.innerHTML = "Testing";
  dLPM.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } else {
  dLPM.style.position = "asfdasfdasfd";
 }


 //RAM Stats//
 //document.getElementById("freeRam").innerHTML = getRam() + "MB";
 document.getElementById("freeRam").innerHTML = "1000MB";

 //devicename//
 //document.getElementById("dName").innerHTML = deviceName();
 document.getElementById("dName").innerHTML = "ShadowEvil's iPhone";
}
```

```css
html
{
 position:absolute;
 margin:0px 0px;
 padding: 0;
}

@font-face
{
 font-family: def;
 src: url(../Fonts/Nokio-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
 font-family: def1;
 src: url(../Fonts/Nokio-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face
{
 font-family: def2;
 src: url(../Fonts/Nokio-Medium.ttf);
}

body
{
 background: url('../Images/bg.png') no-repeat;
 background-size: 320px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#battLevel
{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:27px;
 left: -30px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 z-index:15;
 text-align:right;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
} 

#BatteryImage
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 22px;
 height: 7px;
 top:29px;
 left: 292px;
 z-index:10;
 border: 1px solid white;
 Border-radius: 15px;
}

#isCharging
{
 margin-top: -6px;
 margin: -6px auto 0 auto;
 width: 20px;
 height: 7px;
 background: url('../Images/charging.png') no-repeat;
}

#isLowPowerMode
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 254px;
 top: 29px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 z-index: 15;
 background-color: limegreen;
 Border-radius: 10px;
}

#BatteryImage #BatteryImageLevel
{
 margin-top: 1px;
 margin-left: 1px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 5px;
 z-index:15;
 background-color: limegreen;
 Border-radius: 15px;
}

#freeRam{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:27px;
 left:0px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index:15;
}

#dName
{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:21px;
 left:0px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 z-index:15;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#DateWrap
{
 position: absolute;
 width:320px;
 top:30px;
 left:0px;
 color:fffffd;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family: def1;
 z-index:16;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#line{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:42px;
  width:320px;
  Border-radius:0;
  background-color: #383838;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:0.85;
}
#circle3{
  position: absolute;
  top:21px;
  left:250px;
  height:45px;
  width:45px;
  Border-radius:100px;
  background-color:383838;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:1.0;
}
#circle4{
  position: absolute;
  top:26px;
  left:256px;
  height:35px;
  width:35px;
  Border-radius:100px;
  background-color:fffffd;
  border: 1px solid none;
  z-index:8;
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>P.iW.14</title>
<!--Scripts JunesiPhone, IS2 Matchstic, mod J3T,-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, height=568, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <script src="Config.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/Library/lang.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<script src="js/IS2.js"></script>
<script src="js/Library/clock.js"></script>
<script type="text/cycript">
      var getBatteryPercent = function() { return [IS2System batteryPercent]; };
   var getBatteryState = function() { return [IS2System batteryStateAsInteger]; };
   var getRam = function() { return [IS2System ramFree]; };
   var getSignal = function() { return [IS2Telephony phoneSignalBars]; }; 
   var airplaneMode = function() { return [IS2Telephony airplaneModeEnabled]; }
   var WifiOn = function() { return [IS2Telephony dataConnectionAvailableViaWiFi]; }; 
   var WifiSignal = function() { return [IS2Telephony wifiSignalBars]; }; 
   var deviceName = function() { return [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]; };
   var isLowPower = function() { return [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isLowPowerModeEnabled]; };
</script>

<body onload="init()">
<!--Library that handles clock info NO-EDIT-->
       <div id="DateWrap">
  <a id="month"></a> <a id="date"></a> <a id="year"></a>
       </div>
    <script src="js/clockMain.js"></script>
<!--END Clock Widget-->

<div id="line"></div>
<div id="isLowPowerMode"></div>
<div id="battLevel"></div>
<div id="BatteryImage"><div id="BatteryImageLevel"></div><div id="isCharging"></div></div>
<div id="freeRam"></div>
<div id="dName"></div>

<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;

if(width == 375)
{
 viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
 viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.18, maximum-scale=1.18, user-scalable=0');
} else if(width == 414 ) {
 viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
 viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.3, maximum-scale=1.3, user-scalable=0');
}

</script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you... I don't know why I kept adding that... Works like a charm now... Lol